# Scalding: Add trait from separate file

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

I have several scalding jobs that contain a bunch of constants and a few functions that are consistent across all the jobs.  When I need to make a change to one of those, I don't want to change it in 5 different places.  I wanted to create a trait that would store those things but I am having trouble referencing/importing the trait into my job.

So I have a file called constants.scala that contains:

```
 trait constants {a bunch of stuff defined here}
```

In one of my jobs, called myJob.scala I try to define a class like this:

```
class TrxnAmts(args : Args) extends Job(args) with constants {
    All my other code goes here
}
```

I try to run myJob in HDFS adding constants.scala to the classpath using the command:

```
scalding/scripts/scald.rb --hdfs --cp /path/to/constants.scala /path/to/myJob.scala
```

constants.scala appears in the classpath but nothing in the trait is recognized.  How do I make this work?  Do I need to compile constants.scala and reference the class or compile it into a jar first?  Is there a better way to go about this?

Not very experienced with OOP so hopefully I'm not asking a really basic/obvious question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have compiled `.jar` files in the classpath, not `.scala` or `.java`.
Use e.g. [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html) to build them.